# How to solve $\left|2x^2-3x-3\right|>\:x^2-x+12$?

Tags: inequality

I don't know how to solve previous equation

$\left|2x^2-3x-3\right|>\:x^2-x+12$

Comment: Substitute $1-x=y$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $(u=1-x)$ then $du=-1$

Then we integrate $x(u^{\frac{5}{2}})$ and $x=1-u$ clearly.

Then:
$(u-1)(u^{\frac{5}{2}})=(u^{\frac{7}{2}})-(u^{\frac{5}{2}})$

integrating that leads to:
$\frac{(2u^{\frac{9}{2}})}{9}-\frac{(2u^{\frac{7}{2}})}{7}$

Plug back in:
$\frac{(2(1-x)^{\frac{9}{2}})}{9}-\frac{(2(1-x)^{\frac{7}{2}})}{7}$